# MySQL DAYOFWEEK() - my week begins with monday

Tags: mysql

I'm using [DAYOFWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function in MySQL which returns **1** for **sunday**. But in my country the week starts with *monday*, not *sunday*. Is there any chance to get dayofweek from MySQL formated like: (1 - Monday, 2 - Tuesday, ...) ?

Comment: I know it can be done with some nasty conditions. I even tried modulo approach which seems to me non-working (because of weird Modulo implementation in MySQL). Nothing worked for me so far.

Comment: it is a mysql bug. Weeks start on monday as per iso standard. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: It is not a bug. `DAYOFWEEK()` use ODBC standard.

Comment: While I agree with @rgtk it's not a "bug" I'd say ISO should have superseded ODBC.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use `WEEKDAY()` instead of `DAYOFWEEK()`, it begins on Monday.

If you need to start at index 1, use or `WEEKDAY() + 1`.

Comment: Sometimes I'm just dumb. I could figure out, that such function is natively supported by MySQL. Thank you nos.

Comment: it's not you that's dumb. Why would weekday return a different value than dayofweek? That's a dumb idea by mySQL.

Comment: ISO 8601 mandates that Monday=1 etc. to Sunday=7 so I would expect at least one function in mySQL to return such value.

Answer (score 19):

Try to use the [`WEEKDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function.

> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 =
>   Sunday).

Answer (score 8):

How about subtracting one and changing Sunday

```
IF(DAYOFWEEK() = 1, 7, DAYOFWEEK() - 1)
```

Of course you would have to do this for every query.

Comment: 1=Sunday is ODBC standard, so it would have to be in query I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the MODE argument:

[MySQL ::   MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: 12.7 Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

If the mode argument is omitted, the value of the default_week_format system variable is used:

[MySQL ::   MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 5.1.4 Server System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format)

Comment: I think this is actually the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could write a udf and take a value to tell it which day of the week should be 1 would look like this **(drawing on answer from John to use MOD instead of CASE)**:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `reporting`.`udfDayOfWeek`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION `reporting`.`udfDayOfWeek` (
  _date DATETIME,
  _firstDay TINYINT
) RETURNS tinyint(4)
FUNCTION_BLOCK: BEGIN
  DECLARE _dayOfWeek, _offset TINYINT;
  SET _offset = 8 - _firstDay;
  SET _dayOfWeek = (DAYOFWEEK(_date) + _offset) MOD 7;
  IF _dayOfWeek = 0 THEN
    SET _dayOfWeek = 7;
  END IF;
  RETURN _dayOfWeek;
END FUNCTION_BLOCK
```

To call this function to give you the current day of week value when your week starts on a Tuesday for instance, you'd call:

```
SELECT udfDayOfWeek(NOW(), 3);
```

Nice thing about having it as a udf is you could also call it on a result set field like this:

```
SELECT
  udfDayOfWeek(p.SignupDate, 3) AS SignupDayOfWeek,
  p.FirstName,
  p.LastName
FROM Profile p;
```