# mysql week from Monday till Sunday

Tags: mysql

i want to group my data by yearweek but the week starts here in sunday.
how can i group my week from monday till sunday?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(dateStats) k,dateStats udate, COUNT(f_shop) sales
FROM sal_import WHERE dateStats BETWEEN "2011-08-15" AND "2011-08-21" GROUP BY YEARWEEK(dateStats)
```

The Between has a date from Monday till Sunday and i need just one row at the result.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202919/mysql-dayofweek-my-week-begins-with-monday

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Second argument of `YEARWEEK(date[,mode])` function is `mode` - like in [`WEEK(date[,mode])`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function.

You can specify start day - default is `0 (Sunday)`.

Just set it to `1 (Monday)`:

```
YEARWEEK(dateStats, 1)
```

Comment: This is really brilliant way, this type of problem does bother me sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable for this purpose:

[More Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format)

If you are lazy it's

```
  --default_week_format=1
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is not possible because of [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30454).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a date dimension for this type of work. This allows you to specify different attributes for dates, such as "Weekday", "Weekend", "Week number", "Financial Quarter", etc.

See my answer to the following question for more information;

[Select all months within given date span, including the ones with 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093924/select-all-months-within-given-date-span-including-the-ones-with-0-values)

Then, you can create columns with both of the different YEARWEEK type values, join your data to the dimension table, and produce results for either of them without having to change settings, etc.

Hopefully this will help you somewhat!