# Select and count results group where date is today and this week

Tags: mysql

I currently have:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM Events 
WHERE TO_DAYS(EventDate) - TO_DAYS(NOW()) >= 7;
ORDER BY EventDate
```

But what I'd like to do is count only upcoming results and to show how many are today and how many are in the current week, so not 7 days, but the actual Monday - Sunday working week. Is this possible with 1 query?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (
           SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM events WHERE WEEK( EventDate ) = WEEK( NOW() ) 
          ) as counter
FROM events
ORDER BY EventDate
```

Try this, hopefully it will select all the information and then as a sub-query count the total events for the week.

Comment: How do I go about showing the counted results relating to today/this week? By the way, you've got a typo on ORDER BY.

Comment: You should be able to get the result by looking at the counter variable in the result from the query.  Are you able to see the other results that you expect to see?

Comment: Returning no results unfortunately. Edit: Have just removed WHERE DATE(EventDate) = DATE(NOW()) and it's showing a result although obviously that's not ideal.

Comment: Have got it now using `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);` Thanks!

Comment: One issue I've just noticed, the WEEK() groups them however it takes Sunday as the first day of the week. How do I start the week on a Monday? I just tried +1 thinking it may work, but no joy.

Comment: Beat me too it, found this, accepted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914396/mysql-week-from-monday-till-sunday