# Day of week starting at Monday in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it possible to extract day of week starting at Monday - as stated in ISO 8601 - from date in MySQL?

`DAYOFWEEK()` returns `1=Sun..7=Sat`, so is `%v` in `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Comment: Good question! However, you'll probably find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202919/mysql-dayofweek-my-week-begins-with-monday

Comment: Thank you, my Googling skills are not so good after all.

Comment: Haha, sometimes you miss all the right keywords. Happens to me all the time. That's why you should leave this one here, as a pointer to others who search with a title like yours.