# Group by day of week and hour of day in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a column with filled with time stamps

eg.

```
               col1
2017-01-01 10:30:00
2017-01-02 08:10:00
...
```

I want to group by day of week then further group by hour of day.

The output would look like

```
day  hour  count
  1     1      5
        2     12
  2     1     10
        5      3
  ...
```

How would I implement this in SQL? 
I am using MySQL.

Comment: Day 1 for Monday?

Comment: I believe SQL implements 1 as Sunday using the dayofweek() function?

Comment: ANSI SQL has no such function. Perhaps MySQL has? ISO 8601 says Monday is day 1. Since different countries have different ways, you'd better specify what you want.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I am using MySQL. From what I know, it is Sunday as day 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the extraction of weekday and hour in a derived table. `GROUP BY` its result, Something like:

```
select d, h, count(*)
from
(
    select dayofweek(col1) d, hour(col1) h
    from tablename
) dt
group by d, h
```

**Note:** Since I don't know MySQL you may need to adjust the dayofweek and hour parts...

Answer (score 0):

```
select getdate() as Dates into #temp

select datepart(DAY,dates), datepart(hour, dates), count(*) from #temp group by dates
```

is how I did it utilizing the `datepart` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql functions dayofweek and hour in group by

In mysql :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  col TIMESTAMP
) ;

INSERT INTO test (col) VALUES
  (TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 7, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 1, CURDATE()))),
  (TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 6, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 2, CURDATE()))),
  (TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 7, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 3, CURDATE()))),
  (TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 7, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 10, CURDATE()))),
  (TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 7, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 1, CURDATE()))),
  (TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 6, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 2, CURDATE())))
;

SELECT dayofweek (col), hour(col), count(*)
FROM test GROUP BY dayofweek(col), hour(col);
```

Comment: About sunday as day 1, look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202919/mysql-dayofweek-my-week-begins-with-monday